# Responsive image, horizontally and vertically

Tags: css, responsive-images

```
My goal is to:
        As the window is resized horizontally:
           the <img> is clipped left and right equally,
           but the height is not changed.
           Expanding/shrinking width from the center -> left/right.

         As the image is zoomed + or -:
           its height is clipped top and bottom equally,
           but its width is not changed.
           Expanding/shrinking height from the middle -> top/bottom.
         and:
           its width behaves just like window resizing above.

         with zooming, the dimensions of the visible area do not change.
           what is showing is zoomed + or -.
```

I definitely have looked at most of the attempted solutions presented here ... they succeed horizontally on window resize, but fail in both directions with zooming.

Here's my initial attempt at the code which does what I ask for window resizing, but fails for zooming.

```
<div id="headerImage" class="centerImage LoveSongGIF">
</div>
```

A tad more code:

```
.centerImage {
    display:      block;
    margin-left:  auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#headerImage {
    width:  100%;;
    height: 24.125em;       
}

.LoveSongGIF {
    background-attachment: fixed !important;;
    background-color:      white;
    background-image:      url("../images/Love_Song.gif");
    background-repeat:     no-repeat;
    background-position:   center center;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:    cover;
    -o-background-size:      cover;
    background-size:         cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, use the following meta tag in your head area of your HTML.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intital-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

This will automatically set the width and height of images depending on the size of the device screen. It also does this for the other elements in your DOM as well.

Comment: Quite accidentally I discovered that the existence of the background-attachment: fixed !important; caused many of the problems I have listed above. BTW, I noticed that I did not have a problem with this attachment statement in the <body>, but only for a background image in a sub <div>. Cannot figure out why?